# CentOS 5.11: yum installs, but packages remain missing

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I'm trying to figure out a very strange problem with `yum` on a fairly old CentOS 5.11 VPS using DirectAdmin.

Executing the following command suggests the `telnet` package is installed:

```
# yum install telnet
...
Installed:
  telnet.x86_64 1:0.17-41.el5
```

However, `telnet` is still missing:

```
# which telnet
/usr/bin/which: no telnet in (/root/local/node/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/share/adt-bundle/tools:/root/share/adt-bundle/platform-tools)
```

My version of Yum is 3.2.22.

Perhaps a hint of what is going wrong is that I appear to have different versions of `rpm` installed somehow. If I try to verify my RPM database, my database version appears invalid:

```
# rpm --version
RPM version 4.3.3
# rpm --verify telnet
rpmdb: Program version 4.2 doesn't match environment version
error: db4 error(22) from dbenv->open: Invalid argument
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 - Invalid argument (22)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
package telnet is not installed
```

If I rebuild the RPM database using the following command:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db* && rpm --rebuilddb
```

Yum gives a similar error, but complaining about a newer version:

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
rpmdb: Program version 4.3 doesn't match environment version
error: db4 error(-30974) from dbenv->open: DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 -  (-30974)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
```

Removing the `/var/lib/rpm/__db*` files gets Yum past this again, but installed packages still appear to be missing.

I get the feeling that Yum is somehow misconfigured or that I have two different versions of RPM. What can I do to diagnose the problem to ultimately work to a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your rpm install which is somehow off.  I would expect on CentOS 5.11 with yum 3.2.22 installed that your rpm version would be 4.4.2.3, not 4.3.3

Specifically the rpm-libs package installs /usr/lib64/librpmdb-4.4.so which
yum 3.2.22 requires but I am guessing you have /usr/lib64/librpmdb-4.3.so

I suggest you download the new rpm-*4.4.*rpm from the updates repo and install them with rpm by hand.

Comment: Thanks, that seems likely. I took a look, and I have both librpmdb-4.3.so and librpmdb-4.4.so in lib64. (Also librpmio.) How could I best go about removing 4.3?